# Laravel Multi Tenancy Query Builder use wrong database

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant

I use spatie laravel multi tenancy.

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v1/installation/using-multiple-databases

I want to do a simple query with query builder.

```
DB:table('users')->select('username')->get(); // i would like use this
```

But use wrong database `homestead`. If I use the model it works fine.

```
User::select('username')->get();
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

using the DB Facade you should specify the connection name like so:

```php
DB::connection('tenant')->table('users')->....
```